# Blender 3.5 not working on my system

Tags: versions, hardware

I have been using blender on my PC. (Intel i5 processor, 4G ram, internal Intel graphics card, CPU rendering only) Currently, I am using 3.41, but if I try to use 3.5 as a look-see, Bender mainly loads, but just before it loads completely it crashes out to my desktop. This is a clean factory default effort with no add-ons.

Just wondering, is this the end of the line for me? Or is there an explanation? I welcome any advice.

Thanks
Mer

Comment: I'm not sure there are any different requirements for 3.5 over 3.4.1. From the minimum requirements [here](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) I'm surprised that 3.4 runs on your PC considering the amount of RAM you have!

Comment: Is not officially out yet, so there are probably some bugs. as metioned by the other comment, your hardware have low specs so you need to check the requirements for Blender

Comment: Yes my system is a bit long in the tooth, 10+ years. Up to the release candidate 3.5 all was well, albeit slow at rendering. I do need to update my system, but I'm no spring chicken myself, so I'll have to consider carefully what I need to get. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Well, I've tried the official released version and that fails to start as well. Therefore I've decided to bite the bullet and upgrade my system. So, hopefully if all goes well, it'll be AMD Ryzen 5600X, 32G DDR4, 8G RTX 3060TI, 1Tb M.2 SSD, 1Tb SATA SSD. I hope that's enough to make it go. Any further advice is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problems (it's now after official release).
My PC is a Gen 11 Intel i7 with 64Gb RAM, a 1Tb SSD and 8Tb HDD and an Nvidia 3060, all very new and fast.
Previous versions were fine.  3.5 gives me Not Responding warnings very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I think 3.5 might have a few bugs. Blender 3.0 to 3.4 was rock solid. On 3.5 I get not responding errors, especially after my computer wakes from sleep or hibernate.

As far as system specs blender can run on a potato as long as the scene you're working with is simple, and your render options are reasonable. If you crank up the polygon count for example you WILL run into issues with 4gb of ram.

Answer (score -2):

Same problem here: blender crashes on startup.

What I found out: the problem with blender version 3.5 and 3.5.1 is that the config is missing. It is still there up to ver. 3.4, but with the next version its gone.

Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn´t help. I think the team of blender has to take a look again into it and to publish a new version asap.